# Where is " joint_command_handle.hpp" in MoveIt2(v2.1.0)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have one error after "colcon build" with MoveIt2 (v2.1.0) on ROS2-foxy-desktop/Ubuntu 20.04/Docker container.
I have already check the Dockerfiles in "https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/tree/main/.docker".
I want to build moveit2 from source codes, because I want to run the moveit on arm64v8.

```
In file included from /opt/ws_moveit/src/fake_joint/fake_joint_driver/src/fake_joint_driver_node.cpp:10:
/opt/ws_moveit/src/fake_joint/fake_joint_driver/include/fake_joint_driver/fake_joint_driver.h:12:10: fatal error: hardware_interface/joint_command_handle.hpp: No such file or directory
  12 | #include <hardware_interface/joint_command_handle.hpp>
```

Could you please suggest the issue ?

Best regards,
JiGoRo

console logs

```
$ colcon build --event-handlers desktop_notification- status- --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --ament-cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Starting >>> urdfdom_headers
Starting >>> geometric_shapes
Finished <<< urdfdom_headers [3.28s]
Starting >>> moveit_msgs
Finished <<< geometric_shapes [16min 21s]
Starting >>> srdfdom
Finished <<< srdfdom [2min 19s]
Starting >>> urdfdom
Finished <<< urdfdom [3min 21s]
Starting >>> hardware_interface
Finished <<< hardware_interface [5min 36s]
Starting >>> moveit_resources_panda_description
Finished <<< moveit_resources_panda_description [4.52s]
Starting >>> moveit_resources_fanuc_description
Finished <<< moveit_resources_fanuc_description [4.43s]
Starting >>> moveit_resources_pr2_description
Finished <<< moveit_resources_pr2_description [5.42s]
Starting >>> controller_interface
Finished <<< controller_interface [27.7s]
Starting >>> moveit_resources_panda_moveit_config
Finished <<< moveit_resources_panda_moveit_config [4.93s]
Starting >>> moveit_resources_fanuc_moveit_config
Finished <<< moveit_resources_fanuc_moveit_config [10.7s]
Starting >>> test_robot_hardware
Finished <<< test_robot_hardware [2min 2s]
Starting >>> controller_manager
Finished <<< moveit_msgs [30min 37s]
Starting >>> moveit_core
Finished <<< controller_manager [5min 34s]
Starting >>> moveit_resources
Finished <<< moveit_resources [5.05s]
Starting >>> joint_state_controller
Finished <<< joint_state_controller [3min 52s]
Starting >>> joint_trajectory_controller
Finished <<< joint_trajectory_controller [6min 19s]
Starting >>> transmission_interface
Finished <<< transmission_interface [2min 0s]
Starting >>> ros2_controllers
Finished <<< ros2_controllers [4.99s]
Starting >>> diff_drive_controller
Finished <<< diff_drive_controller [4min 19s]
Starting >>> ros2_control
Finished <<< ros2_control [5.40s]
Starting >>> fake_joint_driver
--- stderr: fake_joint_driver
In file included from /opt/ws_moveit/src/fake_joint/fake_joint_driver/src/fake_joint_driver_node.cpp:10:
/opt/ws_moveit/src/fake_joint/fake_joint_driver/include/fake_joint_driver/fake_joint_driver.h:12:10: fatal error: hardware_interface/joint_command_handle.hpp: No such file or directory
   12 | #include <hardware_interface/joint_command_handle.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fake_joint_driver_node.dir/build.make:63: 
CMakeFiles/fake_joint_driver_node.dir/src/fake_joint_driver_node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: CMakeFiles/fake_joint_driver_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< fake_joint_driver [15.2s, exited with code 2]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362126/where-is-%22-joint_command_handle.hpp%22-in-moveit2(v2.1.0)/) by [JiGoRo](https://answers.ros.org/users/59942/jigoro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're probably running into [ros-planning/moveit2#283](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/issues/283).

`ros2_control` is still being developed. There are frequent API (and ABI) breakages. MoveIt2 didn't keep up, so the build broke.

[ros-planning/moveit2#284](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/pull/284) was submitted which should work-around it for now.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JiGoRo](https://answers.ros.org/users/59942/jigoro/) on 2020-09-24**:
Thank you for your great support !

I'm happy to get this information about [ros-planning/movei2#284](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/pull/284)

I have succeeded to build and run moveit2 on arm64v8.

Best regards,
JiGoRo